# Troubles with implicit error type conversion

Tags: rust, error-handling

I am trying to bring multiple disparate error types into a single composite error type. I am having trouble understanding why implicit type conversion is not taking place in my example:

```
use std::io::Error;

struct ParseError;

enum CompositeError {
    IoError(std::io::Error),
    ParseError(ParseError)
}

impl From<std::io::Error> for CompositeError {
    fn from(error: std::io::Error) -> Self {
        CompositeError::IoError(error)
    }
}

impl From<ParseError> for CompositeError {
    fn from(error: ParseError) -> Self {
        CompositeError::ParseError(error)
    }
}

fn open_file(path: &str) -> Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error> {
    std::fs::File::open(path)
}

fn parse_file(file: std::fs::File) -> Result<bool, ParseError> {
    Err(ParseError)
}

fn open_file_and_parse(path: &str) -> Result<bool, CompositeError> {
    open_file(path).and_then(|f| parse_file(f))
}

fn main() {
    match open_file_and_parse("C:\\rust-sandbox\\src\\main.rs") {
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(e) => {
            match e {
                CompositeError::IoError(_) => {}
                CompositeError::CustomError(_) => {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:32:23
   |
32 |         .and_then(|f| parse_file(f))
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                       |
   |                       expected struct `std::io::Error`, found struct `ParseError`
   |                       help: try using a variant of the expected enum: `Ok(parse_file(f))`
   |
   = note: expected enum `Result<_, std::io::Error>`
              found enum `Result<bool, ParseError>`
```

I expected that the `open_file(path).and_then(|f| parse_file(f))` line would automatically detect that it should be returning a `CompositeError`, and do the type conversions using the `From` trait implementations, but evidently I am incorrect.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can use the `?` operator to coerce the error, `Ok(parse_file(open_file(path)?)?)` (perhaps split up in a `let` binding for clarity). Or you can use `.map_err(Into::into)` to convert results into `Result<_, CompositeError>`.

Comment: `and_then` doesn't use the same mechanism as the question mark operator, the unstable `Try` trait, instead it expects the error type to be the same. You can confirm this by checking it's signature: `impl<T, E> Result<T, E> { fn and_then<U, F>(self, op: F) -> Result<U, E> }`, it only modifies the `Ok` type, not the `Err` type.

Comment: I invite you to use [snafu](https://crates.io/crates/snafu) cause it's perfectly help you do what you want here.

Answer (score -2):

because open_file return Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error> but expected to be Result<bool, CompositeError>

```
fn open_file_and_parse(path: &str) -> Result<bool, CompositeError> {
    let _ = open_file(path).and_then(|f| parse_file(f))?;
    Ok(true)
}
```